# How to use vendor React modules / components within a rails application with only react-rails gem?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs

Using [this](https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/issues/160#issuecomment-192427332) comment, I am trying to use Draft.js in my rails application.

But I constantly get the error:

`Draft.min.self-b1d4414….js?body=1:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: Immutable is not defined`

Can anybody tell, what is the *possibly obvious* mistake that I am making?

Details:

I use only react-rails to keep things simple. Gemfile has following related lines:

```
gem 'react-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
```

I placed `Draft.min.js` under `app/assets/javascripts/externallibraries/`
and `Draft.css` under `app/assets/stylesheets/externallibraries`.

The related files, `application.js`:

```
/*
 //= require jquery
 //= require jquery_ujs
 //= require turbolinks
 //= require react
 //= require react_ujs
 //= require bootstrap-sprockets
 //= require react
 //= require react_ujs
 //= require externallibraries/Draft.min
 //= require components
 //= require_tree .
*/
```

And `application.css`:

```
/*
 *= require externallibraries/Draft
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
*/
```

And finally my jsx file is:

```
class NewPost extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            editorState: EditorState.createEmpty()
        };
        this.onChange = (editorState) => this.setState({editorState});
    }

    componentDidMount(){
    }

    componentWillMount() {
    };

    componentWillUnmount() {
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if(JSON.stringify(this.props.some_field) !== JSON.stringify(nextProps.some_field) && nextProps.retrieved_data != null) // Check if it's a new user, you can also use some unique, like the ID
        {
            this.setState({some_field: nextProps.some_field});
        }
    } 

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {"My state is: " + JSON.stringify(this.state, null, "   ")}
                {"And my props are: " + JSON.stringify(this.props, null, "  ")}
                <Editor editorState={this.state.editorState} onChange={this.onChange} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution that I found. Maybe someone's day can be saved:

1. Install the package in rails project's root. Rather than using yarn seems better. The command is `yarn add draft-js`.
2. In `config/application.rb`add following row in the class:

   `config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('node_modules', 'draft-js', 'dist')`
3. In `app/assets/javascripts` add following to `application.js`:

   //= require Draft